# Failed to fetch during update. something is going wrong with ppa

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I am using ubuntu 11.10 since yesterday and I can not install anything from a PPA. Is this a 11.10 problem?

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

How could i change the oneiric to natty in sources list?

Answer (score 1):

That PPA is not yet ready for oneiric. Try change **oneiric** to **natty** in sources list